# UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow is nil inside test of framework

Tags: frameworks, xctest

I am trying to test (using XCTest framework) view controllers that reside inside a framework (dynamic library).  I am running into a problem with the property UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow, which is nil.  I have the following code:

```
override func setUp() {
  super.setUp()

  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: STORYBOARD_NAME_REPORT,
                                bundle: BundleUtil.getCurrentBundle())
  let chatViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(VIEW_CONTROLLER_ID_TIP_CHAT) as UIViewController

  let navigationController = UINavigationController()
  let viewControllers = [chatViewController]
  navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllers

  // PROBLEM: The following causes a crash because keyWindow is nil.
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController = chatViewController

  // Force the view controller to be loaded.
  // Source: https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-testing-view-controllers-swift/
  let _ = navigationController.view
  let _ = chatViewController.view
}
```

Any ideas how to make the keywindow property initialize properly?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: 2018 still need an answer for this

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting it like below:

Get the shared window first and assign the view controller as root controller

```
var window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!
window.rootViewController = viewController
```

and then make the window key and visible.

```
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
CATransaction.flush() //optional
```